# Function of one class friend of another class

Tags: c++, object, friend, private-members

I have two classes `X` and `Y`.

`Y` has a private member `mark`, `X` has a function `getmark()`.
I declared `getmark()` as a `friend` of `Y`.

Now, how do I access the private member `mark` of `Y` using the `friend` function?

This is the code I have so far

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class X
{
    public:
    int getmark();
};

class Y
{
    int mark;
    public:
    friend int X::getmark();
};

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: Downvoting is no problem.But i would happy if my question is answered.

Comment: In `getmark()`, do something like `Y y; y.mark = 42;`

Comment: If the person who downvoted the question can take a moment to provide the code it would  be a lot helpful.

Comment: @juanchopanza i would like to create objects in the 'main' function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;   

class Y; //forward declaration of class Y
class X
{
    public:
    int getmark(Y);
};

class Y
{   
    int mark;
    public:
    friend int X::getmark(Y);
};

int X::getmark(Y obj){
    cin>>obj.mark;
}

int main()
{
  X a;  
  Y b;
  a.getmark(b);
}
```

At first, when the object a (class X) is created, a forward declaration of class Y is necessary in order to declare the `Y` argument to `X::getmark()`.

Creating object b (class Y) wont be a problem as the compiler knows class X exists (for the friend function).

Then, simply call the function `getmark()` through the object `a`.

Note: It is necessary to declare the function `getmark()` after the declaration of class Y, or else compiler will consider the class Y as an incomplete type.

Answer (score 0):

Just a function to be able to set mark:

```
void Y::setMark(int n)
{
    mark = n;
}
```

Make sure to add function prototype to Y class.

```
int X::getMark(Y &y)
{
    return y.mark;
}


int main
{
    X x;
    Y y;

    y.setMark(5);

    cout << x.getMark(y) << endl;
}
```

Should give output `5`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the implementation of `X::getmark()` is after the definition of `class Y`. Otherwise, `X::getmark()` won't benefit from being a friend of `class Y`.
2. Access the private members of `Y` as you please in `X::getmark()`.

Code:

```
class X
{
    public:
    int getmark();
};

class Y
{
    int mark;
    public:
    friend int X::getmark();
};

int X::getmark()
{
   Y y;
   y.mark = 100;

   // Do whatever you need to do with y.

   return 0;
}
```